# A possible mistake in the statement "The set of all rationals $\Bbb Q$ is the closure of $\emptyset$ in $(\Bbb R,0,1,+,-,\times,\div)$"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Chapter 5. *Operations and Structures* from textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* by Hrbacek and Jech, the authors define *closure* as follows

> [image]

Then the authors mention that

> The set of all rationals $\Bbb Q$ is the closure of $\emptyset$ in $(\Bbb R,0,1,+,-,\times,\div)$.

I think this statement is possibly wrong. I think it should be

> $\emptyset$ is the closure of $\emptyset$ in $(\Bbb R,0,1,+,-,\times,\div)$.

Could you please verify my observation? Thank you for your help!

Comment: "...all constants of A belong to B". If one believes this phrase, one should believe that 0 and 1 belong to any closed set of the structure R. In particular, the emptyset is not closed, hence it cannot be the closure of the emptyset.

Comment: Hi @BUIQuang-Tu, I don't understand whether the statement **all constant of $\mathfrak{A}$ belongs to $B$** is a condition in the definition of **closed**, or it is just a corollary follows from that definition.

Comment: By definition of **closed** which is "A set $B\subseteq A$ is called closed if the result of applying any operation to elements of $B$ is again in $B$, i.e., if for all $j\le n-1$ and for all $a_0,\cdots, a_{f_{j-1}}\in B, F_j(a_0,\cdots, a_{f_{j-1}})\in B$ provided that it is defined", I can not infer how **all constants of $\mathfrak{A}$ belong to $B$**. For reference, in the textbook, the authors identify $0$ in $(\Bbb R,0,1,+,-,\times,\div)$ with operation $\{(\emptyset,0)\}$  and constant  $1$ in $(\Bbb R,0,1,+,-,\times,\div)$ with operation $\{(\emptyset,1)\}$. Please shed some lights!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the definition of "closed" forces $0,1$ to be in the closure of $\emptyset$.  Once you have those, then by repeating $+$, you get all of $\mathbb{N}$, etc.

In summary, $\mathbb{Q}$ is the correct answer.

Comment: Does "closed" or "closure" have a more specific meaning in this context? For me, I would've thought it just saying "0, 1" in there already meant it contains $0, 1$ (if this makes any sense)

Comment: I don't understand whether the statement **all constant of $\mathfrak{A}$ belongs to $B$** is a condition in the definition of **closed**, or it is just a corollary follows from that definition. Could you please elaborate on this point?

Comment: LeAnhDung, a closed set must contain all constants.  Hence $\emptyset$ is not closed.  @Ovi, the closure must contain $0,1$, but also must contain $1+1=2$, and also $1+2=3$, etc.

Comment: By definition of **closed** which is "A set $B\subseteq A$ is called closed if the result of applying any operation to elements of $B$ is again in $B$, i.e., if for all $j\le n-1$ and for all $a_0,\cdots, a_{f_{j-1}}\in B, F_j(a_0,\cdots, a_{f_{j-1}})\in B$ provided that it is defined", I can not infer how **all constants of $\mathfrak{A}$ belong to $B$**. For reference, in the textbook, the authors identify $0$ in $(\Bbb R,0,1,+,-,\times,\div)$ with operation $\{(\emptyset,0)\}$,  and constant  $1$ in $(\Bbb R,0,1,+,-,\times,\div)$ with operation $\{(\emptyset,1)\}$. Please shed some lights!

Comment: A constant is the result of a 0-argument operation.

Comment: Hi @Ted, but the domain of such 0-argument is $\{\emptyset\}$ and $\emptyset \notin \emptyset$.

Comment: @LeAnhDung, all constants belonging to the closure is part of the definition, as quoted by you.  Whether this part of the definition is redundant (and can be inferred from the rest of the definition) or not is immaterial.  Your claim that $\emptyset$ is closed is incorrect.

Comment: @LeAnhDung The domain of an $n$-ary operation on $A$ is the set of all $n$-tuples on $A$.  If $B \subset A$, then $B$ is closed under this operation if for every $n$-tuple all of whose elements belong $B$, applying this operation gives an element of $B$.  A constant $c$ is the 0-ary operation which produces the result $c$.  If $B = \emptyset$, then it is *not* closed under this 0-ary operation because all elements of the 0-tuple belong to $B$ vacuously (since the 0-tuple has no elements) but the result $c$ does not belong to $B$.

Comment: Closure says that if a *particular* tuple in the domain of the operation has all its elements belonging to $B$, then the result of applying the operation to that tuple is also in $B$.  The fact that $\emptyset \not \in \emptyset$ is not relevant here, because $\emptyset$ is not an *element* of any tuple in the domain of the 0-ary operation: $\emptyset$ *is* the 0-tuple, which has no elements.

Comment: Hi @Ted, please confirm if my understanding of your previous comments is correct! Let $B$ be any closed set. Since $\emptyset$ is the only 0-tuple, and all *elements* of 0-tuple belong to $B$ vacuously (since the 0-tuple has no elements). Thus the result of applying any operation taking $\emptyset$ as input will belong to $B$ by the fact that $B$ is closed.

Comment: @LeAnhDung Yes, that is exactly correct!

Comment: Thank you so much @Ted! Your comments are so enlightening and straight to my confusion. That's great!