# Is this a typo in the hint for theorem "The complete ordered field is unique up to isomorphism"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

In Chapter 10. *Sets of Real Numbers* from textbook **Introduction to Set Theory** by Hrbacek and Jech, the authors mention:

> [image]

Let $\mathfrak{R}=\langle \Bbb R,<,+,\cdot,0,1 \rangle$ be the structure of real numbers. Then the closure of $\{0,1\}$ under $+$ and $\cdot$ in $\mathfrak{R}$ is $\Bbb N$. As such, I guess $\mathfrak{C}$ should be isomorphic to $\mathfrak{N}=\langle \Bbb N,<,+,\cdot,0,1 \rangle$, rather than to $\mathfrak{Q}=\langle \Bbb Q,<,+,\cdot,0,1 \rangle$ as mentioned by the authors.

Please verify my observation! Thank you so much!

Comment: Perhaps the book makes the (nonstandard) definition that the closure of a set under some group operations also must be closed under their corresponding inverses?

Comment: Hi @Micah, I have posted a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063400/a-possible-mistake-in-the-statement-the-set-of-all-rationals-bbb-q-is-the-cl) in which i also quoted the authors' definition of **closure**. Please have a look for reference!

Comment: You want an ordered field. The natural numbers are not a field. You have to include multiplicative inverses so you get the rationals.

Comment: You're right.  The author was so immersed in fields he forgot to clarify that the closure  is a field closure.  If it were a group or ring closure it'd be Z instead of N.

Comment: Hi @JohnDouma, did you mean the authors should have written that **the closure $C$ of $\{0,1\}$ under $+,\cdot,-,\div$**?

Comment: Hi @WilliamElliot, What do you meant by **a field closure**? Please give a rigorous definition of **a field closure**!

Comment: No. The author did not make a mistake. You are trying to calculate the smallest ordered field that contains $0$ and $1$. The division sign is not part of the language of fields.

Comment: @LeAnhDung As described by John D.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your comments! I am working toward the proof.